# Create Document Property from data table in spotfire

Tags: spotfire, tibco, spotfire-webplayer, spotfire-analyst

I have the below table in spotfire. And I need to create 2 document properties for baseline_month and monitoring_month. I cannot have a drop_down menu to select the values for document_properties. But I need to create the properties from table itself. I tried for hours, but unsuccessful. Any help here is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is this exactly what your data will look like? Will there be many values in these fields? Whats your key? You could simply set up a cursor in python to pull out the unique value (values?) from the data table.

Comment: Solved. I used ironpython script to get the value as document property.

Answer (score 1):

Document.Properties["BaselineMonth"] = Document.Data.Tables["table_name"].Columns["baseline_month"].RowValues.GetMaxValue().Value